# Is the spring force an applied force or a constraint force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, terminology, spring

The spring force limits the degrees of freedom of a body connected to it, which fits the definition of a constraint force, but the work done by it is not zero. So what do we classify it as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spring force doesn't limit the degrees of freedom of a body connected to it. For instance if you have a mass on one end of the spring and the other is fixed then the body is free to do oscillations and if you given some horizonatal displacement then it's free to move in that direction too. There is no constraint on the body and so it's not a constraint force.

This can be more clear if you consider the force in 3D where the spring constant play a role of tensor and force equation given by
$$F_i=k_{i1}X_1+k_{i2}X_2+k_{i3}X_3$$ Therefore Hooke's law given by
$$\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{k}\mathbf{X}$$

If you define a Applied force as

> An applied force is a force that is applied to an object by a person or another object.

Then you can consider it as Applied force but there are large force or may be all that follow this definition. You can rather call it a Restoring force because that's the property of spring to restore it's initial state.